# Excel - value not found w/ VLookUp but only on some lines

Tags: excel, vlookup

I need your help on the following issue :

The VLOOKUP xls formulas works for some lines but not for all. 
For the lines where the formulas does not work, the result indicated is #N/A. However the value to find is present on the database. I can find it by "copy/paste" handling.

Do you have an idea about the cause of this issue ?

Here is a screen shot of the database (colonne A : value found - colonne K : result to give)

**DataBase**

[image]

and another one for the tab with formulas (rechV = VLookUp in french)

**Result of VLookUp**

[image]

Thank you in advance for your help,
Aurelie

Comment: Most common cause for this Is data mismatch, either lookup value or lookup array might be text formatted while other is a number - this will cause #N/A error. Test with ISNUMBER(O14) and same test for cell with 475256 in other sheet

Comment: I don't see where you are using VLookUp? Also, is `RECHERCHEV` a UDF?

Comment: RECHERCHEV is French version of VLOOKUP

Comment: Are you positive that either the value in the Lookup Table, or the value searched, doesn't have a leading/trailing space or other thing where maybe it's not technically the same?  Copy your cell `O14` and paste in the vlookup table over the current value. Does that do it? (Edit: Ah, that's what @barryhoudini suggested...)